# I am getting following error in my Android Studio Project

Tags: android, android-styles

```
I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/<package_name>-2/lib/arm
I/GMPM: App measurement is starting up
I/AppCompatViewInflater: app:theme is now deprecated. Please move to using android:theme instead.
```

Comment: That's a warning and 3 info log messages, not an error.

Answer (score 1):

`app:theme` is now deprecated. Please move to using `android:theme` instead. It is warning from appcompat library as using `app:theme` attribute in `.xml` is deprecated and it is suggesting to move to `android:theme`.